# VB.NET GUI -- Button click doesnt perform task

Tags: vb.net, loops, button, user-interface

```
Public Class Form1
Public digits As String = "0123456789"
Public userInput As String
Public digitCount As Integer = 0

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    userInput = TextBox1.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    digitCount = userInput.Count(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c))


End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub


Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_MaskInputRejected(sender As Object, e As MaskInputRejectedEventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.MaskInputRejected
    MaskedTextBox1.Text = digitCount.ToString
End Sub
```

I run this program.
I enter in textbox1 my string with numbers.
click Button1.
Nothing appears in MaskedTextBox1.
Any ideas? 
Im at a loss.
I tried everything in my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Button1.Click` event handler you're not actually telling it to do anything to set the value of the `MaskedTextBox`.  That line of code you seem to have placed in the `MaskedTextBox1.MaskInputRejected` handler.  Try refactoring your code like so:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public digits As String = "0123456789"
    Public userInput As String
    Public digitCount As Integer = 0

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        userInput = TextBox1.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        digitCount = userInput.Count(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c))

        MaskedTextBox1.Text = digitCount.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

    End Sub


    Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_MaskInputRejected(sender As Object, e As MaskInputRejectedEventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.MaskInputRejected

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not assigning the output of the digit counting logic to the masked text box, like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MaskedTextBox1.Text = userInput.Count(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c)).ToString()
End Sub
```